# Why is my HashSet storing 2 identical objects with the same hashCode?

Tags: java, hashcode, hashset

I'm doing a school assignment where I need to store a bunch of contacts. Each contact has a `HashSet` of social network accounts, addresses and phone numbers.

I DO NOT want to store multiple copies of the same object in my `HashSet`, so I have overridden the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method for each object.

But for my social network account object only,my `HashSet` is storing the same object twice! 
I have two different objects:

```
SocialNetworkAccount s1 = new SocialNetworkAccount(SocialNetworkAccount.AccountType.FACEBOOK, "wallcrawler123");

SocialNetworkAccount s2 = new SocialNetworkAccount(SocialNetworkAccount.AccountType.FACEBOOK, "wallcrawler123");
```

`s1.equals(s2)` returns `true` and `s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode()` returns `true`, but `s1 == s2` returns `false`!  Why?

This is the `hashCode()` method I'm using:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = result*prime + type.hashCode();
    result = result*prime + id.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please post your `equals` method.

Comment: If the hashes are equal and `equals` considers the two objects equal, the HashSet should keep only one of the two. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your title and post are not in sync, I think.

Comment: @BheshGurung While the post asks why `s1 == s2` returns false, it also says "my HashSet is storing the same object twice". So at most the post contains more than the title, but that shouldn't be surprising ;-)

Comment: My guess / prediction: he created an equals() but with the wrong signature.  The argument has to be Object, not SocialNetworkAccount.

Comment: Given that they claim `s1.equals(s2)` and s1 and s2 have the same hashcode, I'm guessing that they don't realize `s1 == s2` is not equivalent to `s1.equals(s2)`

Answer (score 2):

The == operator compares references. Since there are two different objects, their references will be different.

```
SocialNetworkAccount s1 = new SocialNetworkAccount(SocialNetworkAccount.AccountType.FACEBOOK, "wallcrawler123");

SocialNetworkAccount s2 = s1;

if (s1 == s2) { 
    System.out.println("The references are the same."); 
}
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't explain why `HashSet` stores both of them.  It will call `equals` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is that your `equals` method is *not* overriding [`Object`'s `equals` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), which takes an `Object` as a parameter.

I suspect that your `equals` method takes a parameter of `SocialNetworkAccount`, not `Object`.  I can't know for sure because you haven't posted your `equals` method, but it is a possible explanation.  In this case, the `equals` method in `Object` is *not* overridden, so when `HashSet` (eventually) calls it, it calls `Object`'s `equals` method, which compares references to see if they are the same.

If so, modify your `equals` method to accept an `Object` instead of a `SocialNetworkAccount`, so it overrides `equals` properly.

Also, using the `@Override` annotation will catch when a method that intends to override another method in fact does not override it.

Answer (score 1):

hashCode method is used to coarsly assign entries to the table, but the equals(...) method has to return true for the two instances to be treated as identical.

Since you don't show us the equals method I assume you have not created your own version, which means the HashTable is useing the default implementation, which does `a == b` and your two instances are not the same instance, so that returns false, hence two entries in the table.

What you need to do is implement the equals method too:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o instanceof SocialNetworkAccount) {
        SocialNetworkAccount their = (SocialNetworkAccount)o;
        return xxx.equals(their.xxx ) &&  yyy.equals(their.yyy) && ...;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Replace xxx and yyy and so on with the values in your class.

See the [hashCode and equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: -1 The question states that equals is overriden (second paragraph) and that `s1.equals(s2)` returns true (while `s1 != s2`).

Comment: Yes it does, which I missed, but that's interesting .... I wonder if there's an inheritance hierarchy....

Comment: @delnan The question asserts that, without proof. It seems very likely the OP has done it incorrectly. This answer shows the correct way to do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have done somthing like this?

```
SocialNetworkAccount s1 = new SocialNetworkAccount(SocialNetworkAccount.AccountType.FACEBOOK, "foo");
SocialNetworkAccount s2 = new SocialNetworkAccount(SocialNetworkAccount.AccountType.FACEBOOK, "bar");

hashSet.add(s1);
hashSet.add(s2);

s2.setNickname("foo");

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  // true
System.out.println(hashSet);        // [FACEBOOK:foo, FACEBOOK:foo]
```